# Sum of distances at most ${n \choose 2}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> If $T$ is a tree and $x \in V(T)$ then  $$ s(x) = \sum_{u \in V(T)}
>  d(x,u) \leq {n \choose 2} $$

**My question is:** Is this statement also true for **simple connected** graphs (not necessarily trees)?

***Intuitive approach:*** Since the only difference is that we allow cycles, then in general the distances either decrease or stay the same and thus the inequality still holds. Any thoughts?

Comment: Your approach is not intuitive, it is rigorous

Comment: You are correct. If you want to formalise a proof from your observation, take a spanning tree of the graph and compare the distances in your tree and the whole graph.